# How do you optimize high total blocking time vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, optimization

I have encountered problem that I am not capable of solving. I have high total blocking time on my page (2+ sec). I have tried loading every vue component asynchronously, but it does not matter, still 2+ sec tbt. I don't really understand what can cause such high tbt and what can I do about it, as it is just a simple page without much underlying logic (https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7LSk.png) (Just 21 simple cards).

I have removed everything I can, compressed code, and left only the most nessesary stuff. Still it does not solve the issue. Is there any way to make it go down to 100-200ms? What can cause such a problem in your experience?

I have high amount of components though (cards, buttons, lazy-load picture, rating), so in the end there will be around 100-300 components on page. But I don't see there any possibilities of removing it, as this will break neat structure

Comment: @tony19, hi, I have made a simple live example https://nuxt.itdevv.com, and github project for it accordingly https://github.com/AidOnline01/cards-grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to fix high total blocking time in this case, is to use intersection observer and load it only when it enters the screen. I think same job can do some virtual scroller plugin.

```
<template>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item" v-for="item in items" :data-id="item.id">
      <Item v-if="itemsInScreen[item.id]" :item="item" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Grid',
    props: {
      items: {required: true}
    },
    data() {
      return {
        itemsInScreen: {}
      }
    },
    methods: {
      initObserver() {
        const callback = entries => {
          entries.forEach(entry => {
            if(entry.isIntersecting) this.$set(this.itemsInScreen, entry.target.dataset.id, true);
          });
        };

        const options = {
          rootMargin: "20px 20px 20px 20px"
        };
      
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

        const itemEls = this.$el.querySelectorAll('.grid__item');
        itemEls.forEach(itemEl => observer.observe(itemEl));
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.initObserver();
    }
  }
</script>
```